# prohibit user from closing the form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a main form called `Form_Main`, when somebody wants to close it, it will close the entire application (by entire application I mean quitting other forms as well). Therefore I prepared a yes/no MessageBox that ask users if they really want to quit the form. Here's where I'm at:

```
private void Form_Main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
      DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
      if (result == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          Environment.Exit(1);
      }
      else
      {
          //does nothing
      }
}
```

The "OK" button works. But when users clicks "Cancel", `Form_Main` is closed, but the application is still running (other forms are untouched). What should I replace `//does nothing` with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `FormClosing` event (instead of `FormClosed`), and then set `e.Cancel = true`:

```
private void Form_Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

    e.Cancel = (result != DialogResult.OK);
}
```

The `FormClosing` event occurs *before* the form actually closes, so you still have a chance to cancel it. By the time you get to the `FormClosed` event, it's too late.

Comment: Of course, if you're in `FormClosing`, it isn't necessary to further expedite things with `Environment.Exit()`, now is it?

Comment: in FormClosing, I got an error in Environment.Exit(1)

Comment: You might have read it wrong then.  I think this will be problematic.

Comment: I'll just create a FormClosed event to put the Environment.Exit(1)